# How I can resize a image using fast image?

Tags: ios, ruby

I'm using FastImage on Ruby to resize some images :
https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage_resize/blob/master/test/test.rb

And this is my code, so I had this error since yesterday :

```
class IconExport


  def initialize(img_url,target_directory,tab)
    @img_url=img_url
    @target = target_directory
    @tab = tab
  end



  def export

              @tab.each do |fn, info|
              puts"#{fn} ,#{info}"
              outfile = File.join(@target, "fixtures", "resized_" + fn)
              puts "#{outfile}"
              puts "#{info[1][0] / 3}"
              FastImage.resize(@img_url + fn, info[1][0] / 3, info[1][1] / 2, :outfile=>outfile)
              assert_equal [info[1][0] / 3, info[1][1] / 2], FastImage.size(outfile)
              File.unlink outfile

                      end
    end


end
```

Error :

```
icon2.rb:59:in `block in export': uninitialized constant IconExport::FastImage (NameError)
    from icon2.rb:54:in `each'
    from icon2.rb:54:in `export'
    from icon2.rb:82:in `<main>'
```

Help me please !

Comment: Have you required the library with `require 'fastimage'`?

Comment: Yes that's was my error, http://ruby.about.com/od/faqs/qt/Nameerror-Uninitialized-Constant-Object-Something.htm